# Using ArcGIS Maximum Likelihood Classification gives Error 010108?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, imagery, image

I am trying to find trees of a single species (Cedar) in my orthophoto.  My assumption is that the spectral bands of cedar trees are different to other vegetation (they definitely look different).  I have created about 8 small training areas and united them in one class which I have saved as a signature file.  I get two errors - one that the number of bands in my signature file is less than the number of bands in the raster, and the other is an error executing the grid expression.

> Error 010108: The number of bands in the signature file is less than the number of bands in the raster
>
> Error 010067: Error in executing grid expression

One factor that may be causing this is that my orthophoto is actually composed of a large amount of smaller tiles.  I have created my training areas and signature file within one of the tiles but I want to apply the classification to about 30 of my tiles.  I was getting an error message about extent so I changed the extent values to union of inputs in the environments options but I can't seem to get rid of the other error messages and I am clueless.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the precise steps that lead to one or other of the two error messages.  Asking about both in the same questions goes against the [Tour] and makes it hard for potential answerers to focus on either.